# Objective-C: Saving a sent email as a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I would like to compose and send an email programmatically via an iOS app. On a successful send, I want to be able to store a copy of the sent email as a file so that I can integrate and store the email in a document/contact management system.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, which libraries are available? I have had a look at some of the SMTP libraries on GitHUb but cannot find how to save emails as a file

Comment: Will it be okay if we take a screenshot of the MailComposercontroller when it successfully sends the email?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that probably wont work if the email content  is longer than a screenful

Answer (score 0):

You can not save an email from email composer in iOS.

All you need to do is, You can generate email format file manually with code (as you already have all the data of email) and save it if you get success flag in delegate method when user send an email.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had gathered from MailComposer it isnt possible but was hoping there were some SMTP libraries around that I could use. For example, the .Net SMTP libraries allow an email to be serialized, including attachments

Comment: Ok. Yes with thirds party SMTP library this can be possible. But I don't have much idea about it. Still I will check...